# I can't change my home app in lineageOS 14.1

Tags: lineageos, home-screen

I'm having problems with the home app in lineageOS. I usualy have the Nova Launcher Prime as home app in my phone but now I'm unable to use it because when I'm going to change doesn't appear a diferent app.
If it helps I have a: Vodafone Smart Ultra 6, LineageOS 14.1, Android 7.1.2.
[In the picture is writen Home Aplicarion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vujZF.png)

Comment: Trebuchet is the default launcher of lineage and Cyanogen mod custom roms. Does nova launcher appears in app drawer? Open nova launcher and open Nova settings, go down and tap on select default home and try to set it as default launcher. Please reply if there's any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I open nova launcher (it appears in the app drawer) in the settings it says "Nova Launcher is not set as default click here to set". I press but then it still just appear the default launcher from lineage

Comment: Select Settings > Apps. Then select the gear. In the home app section, select Nova launcher

Comment: Again thanks for the help but the problem is that the nova launcher does not appear when I do that.